# How to send data in email to customer from Magento backened using HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, mysql, email, magento

How to send data in email to customer from comment box present in sales/order/(particular order) of Magento backened using HTML tags?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Generally it's a good idea in the body of your question to expand upon the theme in your title. It is also very useful to show what you have tried - the existence of a helpful community does not mean that a question should be asked prior to any research being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this first of all you need to find on which action your data is posting from that comment box. 
From my information it should be under admin sales order controller and the action name is `

> addCommentAction

`and in that action you will find a

```
$comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));
```

this is tag whicvh removes all the html tags from the post . for your needs just modify it as below

```
$comment = $data['comment'];
```

hope this will work .